# Copy chaindata from one device to another?

Tags: wallets, synchronization, raspberry-pi

After trying to sync the ether wallet with my laptop without success (it took too long and I finally switched off the computer) I started the syncing process from a Raspberry Pi 3 through Geth.

The RPi is being syncing for three days now, chaindata is over 4.2 GB (I don't know how much is still left, is there someway to know?) and I wonder: can I copy that chaindata to my Windows laptop to use it also there with Mist or another wallet app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can copy the chaindata between machines. You need a decent one for the first time sync, because the chaindata is far more than 40GB. But you can download it with a computer, preferably one with a high bandwidth and an SSD, and just copy the chaindata to your Raspberry Pi. On windows, the chaindata is located under

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\geth
```

for Linux and other general information, see [Geth - Backup & Restore](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Backup-&-restore).
But don't forget to keep your Raspberry synced every day, alse it might take it a long time to catch up with the network.

Comment: Thanks! I'm syncing on the Rpi (6.5 GB chaindata downloaded now, around 2.2 GB in these 20 hours) but my microSD is 32 GB so I'm affraid I will have to stop the process. I thought the sync was below 10 GB, wow.

Comment: You're welcome. But not only the size, also the writing speed is important, as it can be a bottle neck for syncing. The overall system performance can also be important. If my answer was useful, please bump it up.